# ejs function keeps inserting unwanted new lines

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have this `for loop` :

```
<% for (let obj of objects) {
   doSomething();
}%>
```

And this function :

```
<% function doSomething() { %>
HelloWorld = "Helloworld"
<% } %>
```

The output for now is like that :

```
HelloWorld = "Helloworld"

HelloWorld = "Helloworld"
```

and it should be :

```
HelloWorld = "Helloworld"
HelloWorld = "Helloworld"
```

Any idea why there a newline inserting?

Comment: provide pen or fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is the new line after `HelloWorld = "Helloworld"` if you write it like this, the output should be what you are looking for

```
<% function doSomething() { %>
HelloWorld = "Helloworld"<%
} %>
```